# My F3 key is not working on Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

so in Minecraft, I am trying to get the coordinates on my pc, but if I press f3 nothing happens, f3+FN, nope. Its really bothering me because I am trying to see the light level of my house. And yes show coordinates is off if that had anything to do with it. I have a HP pc(I forgot which one and I am too lazy to check) and my keyboard is pretty much a Razor keyboard but deferent brand. (I also forgot what keyboard it is) Please help me this is annoying me ALOT.

Comment: its working for everything else, right?

Comment: are you using Java for Windows, or Mac? also, are you using a laptop?  
we're going to need also what your keyboard brand/model is to be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

Show coordinates is not a feature in Java edition. Most likely you are playing on Bedrock edition, which doesn't have a F3 menu. If you are running Java edition, you can look at your keybinds in Escape menu --> Options --> Controls.